# How to update package manager to get package available in 12.04 on 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, apt, updates, package-management, 12.04

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10, which has `libmongodb-perl 0.39-1` available through `apt-get`. I see that version 0.45 is availble in the "precise" (12.04) universe.

How can I update apt to install version 0.45 of this driver?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Install packages from newer release without building (apt pinning)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/103320/install-packages-from-newer-release-without-building-apt-pinning) You do it with pinning, the above link has detailed instructions. Please take care, if you are not careful you can break ubuntu. An alternate to pinning would be backports https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports

Answer (score 1):

You can easily download a single .deb package from any series. In your case the steps will be:

- Go to http://packages.ubuntu.com
- Search for package `libmongodb` in `precise`
- Select appropriate result.
- In section *Download libmongodb-perl* click on the desired architecture.
- Choose mirror (or click on any of them). The download will start.
- Install the downloaded .deb file. Either:

  - open it with Ubuntu Software Center, or
  - use `sudo dpkg -i file.deb`

Similar procedure works for any package you want. Good luck!

Comment: If you are running Ubuntu, it is strongly suggested to use a package manager like aptitude or synaptic to download and install packages, instead of doing so manually via this website.

Comment: @BlueXrider: Unless you need to install a package that is not available in repositories for given series. Aptitude, apt-get, synaptic install packages in the same manner as dpkg does, so there is no difference in installing the packages - the only difference is the source where one downloads the .deb file from. And what better source can there be then the official Ubuntu repositories? (Yes, packages.ubuntu.com are indeed linked to the official repo's and mirrors.)

Answer (score 0):

If that is where the package is at and you want to add the package with apt-get then you need to add the repository to your sources list.

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise universe
```

Then run `sudo apt-get update` then install the package required.

#### Be warned, as this may have undesired effects on the system and related packages.

Comment: Doing that will result on a *partial* upgrade to 12.04 when installing updates.

Comment: I concur this is NOT a good idea, if the OP wants to experiment or develop he should be allowed.

Comment: IMO both pinning and backports are better (safer).

Comment: @BlueXrider: I fail to see that the OP wants to experiment or develop. He just needs a newer version of a single package. Adding precise repositories is **very likely** to break his system the next time he installs updates, and that's not what one may expect when upgrading a single library.