# Update repositories for ubuntu 12.04LTS

Tags: 12.04, apt, official-repositories, add-apt-repository

I got a server running Ubuntu 12.04LTS, and I got a bug in the
 **apache-module** `mod_auth_cas`.

I noticed that because the 12.04 repositories lags far behind on **apache-server** updates and especially on mod_auth_cas, that installing new versions might remedy my situation.

However, `mod_auth_cas` has a series of dependencies, and they might have more dependencies etc.

In short, I'd really like to use **apt-get** or **Synaptic**.

It has been suggested that to get access to the newest mod_auth_cas and apache httpd server,
I can add to my `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy main universe
```

However, will adding this, thus using the repositories of the newer ubuntu-versions, somehow destroy my server? Or is this considered safe?

Answer (score 2):

Your situation can be a disadvantage of using a LTS, the software is more stable, but may be outdated or you may require a newer version of Apache (or other packages) if you have a specific problem.

The short answer to your question is yes, adding the universe repository is considered safe.

For additional information on Repositories see: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

I am not sure, but I would guess Canonical would not necessarily support packages in the Universe repository as it is "community maintained".

IMO I suggest you stay with software in the repositories before adding a ppa.

In general, if you need a more recent version of Apache , or other applications, I would consider upgrading your entire server (rather than adding the saucy repos).

Adding the saucy repositories can be done in theory, using pinning, but it is is asking for problems and to some extent is upgrading your server.

See [Install packages from newer release without building (apt pinning)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103320/install-packages-from-newer-release-without-building-apt-pinning)

I have used pinning with mixed results and I would not advise it unless you consider yourself an experienced ubuntu user and you are willing and able to fix problems.

Personally, I would consider adding the saucy repos (with or without pinning) , without upgrading your server, as unsupported.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this PPA for updating Apache to version 2.4 in Ubuntu 12.04

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2
```

Updating repository

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Updating Apache to 2.4

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

[Read this source](http://www.justincarmony.com/blog/2013/07/31/ubuntu-12-04-php-5-4-apache2-and-ppaondrejphp5/)

Comment: The OP is not asking how to add a repository, or update apache. He is asking if adding an ubuntu repository is "considered safe"