# Ubuntu 14.04 library on 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, opencl

Is there any way to install libraries that have been made available for Ubuntu 14.04 on 12.04?

Specifically I would like to install the OpenCL library on Ubuntu 12.04 without installing a full SDK from a vendor (e.g. NVIDIA, AMD, Intel).  This is easily accomplished on Ubuntu 14.04 by

```
sudo apt-get install ocl-icd-opencl1
```

but this library doesn't appear to be available for 12.04?

Answer (score 0):

I've found this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103320/install-packages-from-newer-release-without-building-apt-pinning) with an extensive answer about [pinning](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto) - does it apply to your case (it's from 2012, but seems to be up to date, version names aside)?