# update to latest version of usb_modeswitch

Tags: upgrade, updates, usb-modem, usb-modeswitch

How can I update to the latest ( currently version 2.2.5) of usb_modeswitch. the version I now have on ubuntu is 2.1.1
I am on Ubuntu 14 and does not wish to upgrade to 15

Thanks

Comment: ubuntu version?

Comment: 2.2.5 is available for willy refer [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=wily&keywords=usb-modeswitch)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install packages from newer release without building (apt pinning)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/103320/install-packages-from-newer-release-without-building-apt-pinning)

Comment: @Ravan: A direct link to the `usb-modeswitch` package in Wily would be https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily/+source/usb-modeswitch.

Comment: @DavidFoerster yes =) I have another one as well https://launchpad.net/~mathieu-tl/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=wily](https://launchpad.net/~mathieu-tl/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=wily)  :)

Comment: @Ravan: Your link is fine just like mine. My mistake. I mistook your linked resource for something else somehow.