# How to compile curl with SSL support?

Tags: 14.04, ssl, curl

I am running on Ubuntu 14.04 and I have manually installed curl 7.48 (see question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36866583/libcurl-not-updated).

I've tried to execute the command:

```
carlo@carlo-ThinkPad-W541:/usr/bin$ curl -sS https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt
curl: (1) Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl
carlo@carlo-ThinkPad-W541:/usr/bin$
```

So I've done a quick check on the configuration output and it clearly said SSL not supported:

```
configure: Configured to build curl/libcurl:

  curl version:     7.48.0
  Host setup:       x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  Install prefix:   /usr/local
  Compiler:         gcc
  SSL support:      no      (--with-{ssl,gnutls,nss,polarssl,mbedtls,cyassl,axtls,winssl,darwinssl} )
```

So I had a look at this link https://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html
And I've tried different commands:

```
root@carlo-ThinkPad-W541:~/curl-7.48.0# ./configure --with-ssl
```

trying to specify where is located my openSSL library:

```
root@carlo-ThinkPad-W541:~/curl-7.48.0# ./configure --with-ssl=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

setting an env variables:

```
root@carlo-ThinkPad-W541:~/curl-7.48.0# export LDFLAGS="-L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/"
root@carlo-ThinkPad-W541:~/curl-7.48.0# ./configure --with-ssl
```

But nothing seems to work, the result is always the same:

```
[...]
configure: Configured to build curl/libcurl:

  curl version:     7.48.0
  Host setup:       x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  Install prefix:   /usr/local
  Compiler:         gcc
  SSL support:      no      (--with-{ssl,gnutls,nss,polarssl,mbedtls,cyassl,axtls,winssl,darwinssl} )
  SSH support:      no      (--with-libssh2)
  zlib support:     enabled
  GSS-API support:  no      (--with-gssapi)
  TLS-SRP support:  no      (--enable-tls-srp)
  resolver:         default (--enable-ares / --enable-threaded-resolver)
  IPv6 support:     enabled
  Unix sockets support: enabled
  IDN support:      no      (--with-{libidn,winidn})
  Build libcurl:    Shared=yes, Static=yes
  Built-in manual:  enabled
  --libcurl option: enabled (--disable-libcurl-option)
  Verbose errors:   enabled (--disable-verbose)
  SSPI support:     no      (--enable-sspi)
  ca cert bundle:   /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  ca cert path:     no
  ca fallback:      no
  LDAP support:     no      (--enable-ldap / --with-ldap-lib / --with-lber-lib)
  LDAPS support:    no      (--enable-ldaps)
  RTSP support:     enabled
  RTMP support:     no      (--with-librtmp)
  metalink support: no      (--with-libmetalink)
  PSL support:      no      (libpsl not found)
  HTTP2 support:    disabled (--with-nghttp2)
  Protocols:        DICT FILE FTP GOPHER HTTP IMAP POP3 RTSP SMTP TELNET TFTP

root@carlo-ThinkPad-W541:~/curl-7.48.0#
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install `libssl-dev`, then `configure` should detect OpenSSL automatically without any flags.

Alternatively, you can install versions > 7.40 [from the Wily or Xenial repositories](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103320/install-packages-from-newer-release-without-building-apt-pinning).

Comment: sudo apt-get install libnghttp2-dev      needed to give curl HTTP-2 support