# Is there a way to install OpenJDK 15 in Ubuntu bionic?

Tags: 18.04, apt, java, openjdk

I would like to use newest Java (15) and I can't find it in ubuntu bionic repositories.
Is there a ppa where I could get it?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can get Java 15 from AdoptOpenJDK PPA.

```
wget -qO - https://adoptopenjdk.jfrog.io/adoptopenjdk/api/gpg/key/public | sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository --yes https://adoptopenjdk.jfrog.io/adoptopenjdk/deb/
```

Then you can install Java 15 with:

```
sudo apt-get install adoptopenjdk-15-hotspot
```

For more information / options / troubleshooting : https://adoptopenjdk.net/index.html

Comment: Do you know what is the difference between adopt and the one from ppa:openjdk-r/ppa ?

Comment: They both come from the same source code and will provide you the same Java capabilities. AdoptOpenJDK let you choose between Hotspot and OpenJ9 JVM. You can see further details here : https://adoptopenjdk.net/about.html or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52431764/difference-between-openjdk-and-adoptium-adoptopenjdk

Answer (score 2):

openjdk-15-jdk is available from the default repositories in Ubuntu 20.10 (and later releases). You can install openjdk-15-jdk from the Ubuntu 20.10 universe repository in Ubuntu 18.04 using [apt pinning](https://askubuntu.com/q/103320/). You can also install openjdk-15-jdk without apt pinning by installing Ubuntu 20.10 in a virtual machine like a KVM/QEMU (*qemu-kvm*) virtual machine created in Virtual Machine Manager (*virt-manager*).

Comment: So ppa:openjdk-r/ppa is no more? I would prefer not to upgrade ubuntu to 20.10 just to get java (which shouldn't depend on the rest of system).
Looks like the best option right now is to download it directly from openjdk.

Comment: Sorry, but that was what I tried first, there is no openjdk-15 or openjdk-15-jdk-headless, there are only <= 14 versions in that ppa :(

Comment: I never saw something like that before in any PPA, but you're right. I manually downloaded openjdk-15 for 18.04 from ppa:openjdk-r/ppa and there was no .deb file in the archive. The archive contained only source code. Even though PPA stands for **P**ersonal **P**ackage **A**rchive, ppa:openjdk-r/ppa didn't package openjdk-15 for 18.04 as a deb file.

Comment: Is there a reason for it not be available on ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: @Sero Please read the answers to [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/q/151283/).

Comment: @karel Well, openjdk 12, 13, 14 were available for bionic, so why not 15? A strange change.