# How to fix Java installation?

Tags: dpkg, java

I've been trying to install Java 15. I installed it a few weeks later on Elementary OS without issues. I switched to Ubuntu today and tried to install it again but this error is driving me mad:

```
download failed
Oracle JDK 15 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java15-installer (--configure):
 installed oracle-java15-installer package post-installation script subprocess 
returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java15-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I used the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java
sudo apt update
sudo apt install oracle-java15-installer
```

Comment: There is something wrong with that installer.  I just tried it and it is giving `--2020-10-21 19:53:13--  https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/15+36/779b
f45e88a44cbd9ea6621d33e33db1/jdk-15_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz?AuthParam=1603331713_3c
406b8486ab7280a476edbbdd1bb2f8
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|104.85.160.29|:443... co
nnected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2020-10-21 19:53:14 ERROR 404: Not Found.` which means until they fix it, or the site is down it cannot be installed.

Comment: Unless you specifically need Java JDK, you can also get a free JDK. I detailed the steps for installing AdoptOpenJDK 15 in this post : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1275754/is-there-a-way-to-install-openjdk-15-in-ubuntu-bionic/1279400#1279400

Comment: Oracle released a new Java version and the PPA wasn't updated with it (once a new Java version is released, you can't install the old one any more). The PPA has now been updated with Oracle Java 15.0.1 so it should work now.

Comment: @Logix Thanks very much. I've been the hole week trying to install it by simply using apt install cause i already had the repository, but i didn't upgrade it. So i removed it today and added it again and worked.