# Install 18.04 packages on 20.04

Tags: apt, ppa

There are a couple of packages which are available for 18.04 which I would like to install on my new installation of 20.04. The issue is that they don't appear to have equivalent version for 20.04.

Specifically I'm looking for `jalview` however more generally having access to bionic packages would be useful. I'd expect that this can be done via a ppa, however I don't know the right one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install packages from newer release without building (apt pinning)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103320/install-packages-from-newer-release-without-building-apt-pinning)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see http://www.jalview.org/getdown/release/install4j/1.8/jalview-2_11_1_1-linux_x64-java_8.sh is on their website, however please do remember to install Java 8 first as that looks like something it relies on. Let me know if this is the correct one!

Answer (score 1):

https://www.jalview.org/getdown/release/install4j/1.8/jalview-2_11_1_2-linux_x64-java_8.sh is a bash installer that will put an (auto-updating) copy of Jalview into your user-space (default `~/opt/jalview`).  The "linux_x64" installer also installs a local Java 8 JRE (found in `~/opt/jalview/jre`) so a separate Java 8 JRE is not required.
Work has started on putting a maintained Jalview into the Debian repository but there's not been a chance to do much work on this yet so it is not going to be soon!