# What is the best method to installing the package "gr-gsm"

Tags: 22.04, gnuradio

What is the best method to install `gr-gsm` on Ubuntu 22.04 that will be compatible with [gnuradio 3.10](https://www.gnuradio.org/news/2022-01-17-gnuradio-v3.10.0.0-release/)?

Comment: Package `gr-gsm` is not available in the apt repositories for Ubuntu 22.04: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gr-gsm&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all It is available in 23.04 and 23.10

Comment: [Installation instructions](https://osmocom.org/projects/gr-gsm/wiki/Installation#Installation-from-packages-on-Debian-Testing-and-Ubuntu-1804)

Comment: @moo that looks like an Answer.

Answer (score 2):

Package gr-gsm is not available in the apt repositories for Ubuntu 22.04. It is available in 23.04 and 23.10: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gr-gsm&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

There are a few options (in approximate order of what I would prefer to do, if it were my system):

1. Update 22.04 to 23.10 using `do-release-upgrade` then install the package with `sudo apt install gr-gsm`
2. Install `gr-gsm` using the [installation instructions](https://osmocom.org/projects/gr-gsm/wiki/Installation#Installation-from-packages-on-Debian-Testing-and-Ubuntu-1804) available on the gr-gsm website
3. You may be able to install the `gr-gsm` package from the newer release without updating your full Ubuntu distribution but this is not straightforward: [Install packages from newer release without building (apt pinning)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103320/install-packages-from-newer-release-without-building-apt-pinning)