# Installing package on different ubuntu version

Tags: apt, package-management, versions

I want to install [this package](https://launchpad.net/~drwright/+archive/stable) on Quantal but it only seems to have Oneiric and Precise versions. So `apt-get update` fails when fetching the package's PPA (it doesn't have a Quantal version). I think the Precise version will probably run fine on Quantal, though.

Is there a way I can manually get the deb and install it with dpkg at my own risk? Or some other way to bypass the "version check".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Just download the `.deb` from the PPA. Nothing is keeping you from doing that. Then install

```
$ sudo dpkg -i packagefile.deb
```

You may need to install the dependencies with it using

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
```

This might not work if it depends on certain versions not provided in Quantal.

If you can't find the `.deb` on the PPA page click "View package details", unfold the source package, then scroll down to "Package Files".

Answer (score -1):

Look at prefer way from the scratch: man apt_preferences and the answer [Install a different version of a package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30305/install-a-different-version-of-a-package)

Comment: -1 because this answer is not useful to the OP; It has no explanations or steps to follow and just link to another question.